# How to verify data received from Request.From[""]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to verify a data written by the user. If the data is not written correctly (dd/MM/yyyy), the application doesn't work. Any ideas how to do that? Examples: if the date format is the correct, if the text box is empty etc.
Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home"))
{
    <label for="datePicker">Type in a date:</label>

    @Html.TextBox("datePicker", @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { id ="datePicker" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="datePickerStart">Type in starting date:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("datePickerStart", @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { id ="datePickerStart" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="datePickerEnd">Type in ending date:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("datePickerEnd", @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { id ="datePickerEnd" })
    <br />
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Search" class='create__btn create__customBtn' />
    <a asp-action="About">Refresh</a>
}
<p>Money earned for the selected date: @ViewBag.SelectedDateSum RON</p>
<p>Money earned in the time period selected: @ViewBag.BetweenSum RON</p>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
public ActionResult About(DateTime? datePicker)
        {
            DateTime userSelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["datePicker"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            
            //value for a selected date
            var allInvoices = _context.Invoices.Where(dd => dd.IssuedDate == userSelectedDate).ToArray();
            int sumFirst = 0;
            foreach (var invoice in allInvoices)
            {
                int x = Int32.Parse(invoice.Value);
                sumFirst += x;
            }
            ViewBag.SelectedDateSum = sumFirst;

            //value between two selected dates
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["datePickerStart"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["datePickerEnd"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            int sumBetween = 0;
            var allInvoices1 = _context.Invoices.Where(dd => dd.IssuedDate >= startDate && dd.IssuedDate <= endDate).ToArray();
            foreach (var invoice in allInvoices1)
            {
                int x = Int32.Parse(invoice.Value);
                sumBetween += x;
            }
            ViewBag.BetweenSum = sumBetween;

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using TryParseExact rather than ParseExact. You can catch malformed user input on the backend this way:

```
public ActionResult About(DateTime ? datePicker) {
    DateTime userSelectedDate;
    //value between two selected dates
    DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["datePicker"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out userSelectedDate)
        && DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["datePickerStart"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate)
        && DateTime.TryParseExact(Request.Form["datePickerEnd"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out endDate))
    {
    //value for a selected date
    var allInvoices = _context.Invoices.Where(dd => dd.IssuedDate == userSelectedDate).ToArray();
    int sumFirst = 0;
    foreach (var invoice in allInvoices)
    {
        int x = Int32.Parse(invoice.Value);
        sumFirst += x;
    }
    ViewBag.SelectedDateSum = sumFirst;


    int sumBetween = 0;
    var allInvoices1 = _context.Invoices.Where(dd => dd.IssuedDate >= startDate && dd.IssuedDate <= endDate).ToArray();
    foreach (var invoice in allInvoices1)
    {
        int x = Int32.Parse(invoice.Value);
        sumBetween += x;
    }
    ViewBag.BetweenSum = sumBetween;

    return View();
} else
{
    //Malformed date was provided
    
}
}
```

Try Parse DateTime Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Int32 and other datatypes also support TryParse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0

There are also guides to provide validation on the front-end but admittedly that isn't my forte:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites

Comment: This was the answer, managed to verify all I need with `TryParseExact` and now I just need to add some attention message.
The thing with `TryParse()` is that always returned False no matter if the date was introduced correctly. Thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-6.0) instead. If it returns false, then call [`ModelState.AddError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and return the view with the model. You can use validators to call out the error form there in the view.